# ld: library not found for -lAeroGear-Push clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, cordova, apple-push-notifications, ionic3, aerogear

**Problem:**
Not able to build the project both using xcode and ionic cli, I do get the below error.

ld: library not found for -lAeroGear-Push clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**What I am trying to do:**

For push notification, I am using aerogear cordova plugin, it works fine in Android but in iOS I do face lot of issues, Is there any solution for this?

Is there any other way to implement a push notification in Ionic 3?

Comment: do you have CocoaPods installed? https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same trouble, it was just the pod dependencies that were not installed :

1. Make sure cocoapods is installed.  This command should display the version if it is installed :

   ```sh
   pod --version
   ```
2. If `cocoapods`is not installed, install it.

   ```sh
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
3. install pods dependecies :

   ```sh
   cd ./platforms/ios
   pod install
   ```
4. Everything should work fine now :

   ```sh
   cordova build ios
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue several builds and weeks after I removed `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` which uses cocoapods. I resolved it by going to the `platforms/ios` directory and running the command `pod install`. After getting a message that there were no dependencies, I closed XCode, re-ran the Ionic build command and opened the XCode workspace file.

The following build worked.

(Ionic v4)